# EF Core create database without tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, fluent-migrator

Is there a ways for EF Core to create the database but not the tables, as all I need is the database to be made, and then run fluent migrator to do the actual migrations?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Why use EF Core at all for this? Just run an ADO.NET query

Comment: Do you mean an empty database, or a database with something in it (procedures? views?), just not tables? In the former case a `CREATE DATABASE foo` statement would be sufficient. EF probably has an appropriate place to hook that somewhere, but if not you could certainly just run that as a plain old SQL command.

Comment: EF core works off a database and manages tables via CodeFirst or DBFirst. Dont think EF can do what you are looking to do

Comment: Ok ill just make the SqlConnection directly then, Thanks for the help